# Fail to install Ubuntu 16.04.1 due to libparted bug

Tags: 16.04

```
sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x68517eba

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048    206847    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2  *       206848 145391615 145184768  69.2G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       145393663 934416383 789022721 376.2G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda4       934416384 976769023  42352640  20.2G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5       145393664 200157183  54763520  26.1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       200159232 209922047   9762816   4.7G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       209922048 934416383 724494336 345.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

I am trying to install Ubuntu on /dev/sda4. But as soon as I try to install, installer crashes. Later, I found that it is due to libpart bug. Any idea why this is happening here?

[image: Ubuntu install crush libparted bug screenshot]

Comment: minitool partition from windows 10 did the trick for me .. i moved the last partition table to desired location of my system

Comment: Great! Now, please, write your solution as an elaborated and detailed answer to your own question and then mark its the wright one. Thus, your question will be marked as solved and other fresh Ubuntians facing the same problem will know that there is a fix for it. Do dare to do it! Open Source and Ubuntu is about giving back! ;-) @nazar2sfive

Answer (score 0):

I couldnot manage to move /dev/sda4 which was physically located as the last partition. So I deleted the partition and merged to /dev/sda7. Then I shrink /dev/sda7 to create a new partition before /dev/sda7.

Basically I moved the last partition (my desired location for ubuntu) to my second-to-last partition using **MiniTool Partition Wizard Free 9.1 in windows 10**. I couldnot do / find any tools in linux to do so without loosing the data. Gparted was showing error from begining. Even diskmgmt.msc from windows 10 was showing some kind of error. MiniTool Partition Wizard Free 9.1 saved my day without loosing any data.

What caused above problem is still a mystery to me.